# SocketIO can't send new message until first will be delivered

Tags: node.js, socket.io

**Situation**:
User has sent image, after image, he will send message. While the second user does not receive a picture, the message will not be sended.

How to send messages normally, like in normal chat?
I have found, that there are "async" module for node.js, but how to use it with Socket IO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply pass every messages in a queue. So each messages must wait for the first one to be send before passing to the next.

Although, here in your case. I don't think waiting for an image to be sent is wise - this will make your chat unresponsive.

Rather, use simple text `image` message. Once you receive this, put a placeholder in the chat where you'll load the image when you received it (displaying a loader meanwhile). This will allow you to continue the chat without being blocked by a long IO process to finish.

Comment: I haven't understood you. If I send the `image` text, then I need to send image too, but how I can do it, when I send Image it will freeze IO. Can you explain more expanded please.

Comment: I mean just a send an event telling an image will be downloaded. (or while receiving the image, send the end user an event as soon as the image start uploading)

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO uses a single WebSocket connection which only allows for sending one item at a time.  You should consider sending that image out-of-band on a separate WebSocket, or via another method.

I have a similar situation where I must stream continuous binary data and signaling messages.  For this, I use [BinaryJS](https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs) to set up logical streams which are mirrored on both ends.  One stream is used for binary streaming, and the other is used for RPC.  Unfortunately, Socket.IO cannot use arbitrary streams.  The only RPC library that seems to work is [rpc-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/rpc-stream).  The RPC functionality isn't nearly as powerful as Socket.IO (in particular when dealing with callbacks), but it does work well.